# Как изменить текст в файле [Java]

Tags: java

Можно ли как то изменить текст в файле который уже существует типо вот в файле написано AB и в программе вписываешь на что хочешь изменить и меняется к примеру на AR

Comment: Можно например построчно прочитать файл и заменить подстроку на какой-то текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
String newStr = "";
while ((newStr = in.readLine()) != null) {
    newStr = newStr.replace("AB","AR");
}
```

**Замена части с строке и сохранение в файл**

Метод contains проверяет содержит ли строка указанную последовательность символов.

```
public class Normalize {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String separator = File.separator;
        String path = "C:" + separator + "files" + separator;
        String f1 = "config.assets";
        String f2 = "config2.assets";

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path + f1)));
        //Поток записи в другой файл
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(path + f2), true);
        String newStr = "";
        while ((newStr = in.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                if (newStr.contains("load")) {
                    newStr = newStr.replace("1", "2");
                }
                out.println(newStr);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл config.assets

```
{"load":1}
```

Comment: Спасибо только у меня возникла проблема с установкой определенного файла я указываю путь к файлу APPDATA\l\config.assets там текст формата json то есть что то типо вот этого {"load":1} и он не хочет заменять цифру на другую мне надо чтобы он проверил есть ли такая строка с названием {"load"} после этого он должен изменить цифру или какое то значение в этой строке ну а так код работает с .txt документами очень хорошо  можете подкинуть для json файлов?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Проверил работает код

Comment: Можно как то сделать чтобы он не перезаписывал файл и не трогал другие строки через , {"load":1 , "ex":www2} у меня не получится понятно обьяснить что именно я хочу сказать